# Relative position and overflow auto

Tags: css, position, overflow

I have a problem with overflow: auto and position relative? Example of my code is:

```css
div {
  border: 3px dashed #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

div::before { content: attr(class); }

.grandparent { overflow: auto; }
.parent { position: relative; }
.child { position: absolute; height: 60px; background: black; color: white; }
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `div.child` go over `div.grandparent` but because of `div.parent` and his `position: relative` that causes overflowing.

Please note that I need to absolutely position elements inside `.parent` - the position being relative to `.parent` - (which is why I need `position: relative` here), and I also need a scrollable `.grandparent`.

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edited the code so the problem shows clearly.

Comment: @connexo position:relative can be removed and you get the expected output. It's not needed if you are not setting top/left/right/bottom values

Comment: @TemaniAfif If I wouldn't need it in my real world scenario, I wouldn't use it. I'm also certain this is a very common scenario in larger web applications.

Comment: @connexo so we need a real scenario here to be solved. You won't find a generic solution to this problem. I have done something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60912860/8620333 that I can apply here but maybe it won't be suitable for your real scenario (I am sure it's for this simple case)

Comment: `position: fixed` won't help here, either. The real world scenario is a tabs webcomponent with scrollable panels (this is the scrolling part). Inside those I need to use a webcomponent reconstruction of a fieldset (which requires absolute positioning on the legend relative to the webcomponent fieldset panel). Inside those panels we have various webcomponents that create absolute positioned dropdowns, datepickers, context menus etc.). I cannot publish any of these since I do not have any rights in the components (I just happen to be the guy developing them).

Comment: Do you want the child to scroll along with grandparent but outside grandparent?

Comment: @Dinesh No, it needs to stay attached to parent.

Comment: why  you need a scrollable .grandparent @Min ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor Because grandparent can contain more element than fit into it. granparent height is restricted by the grid cell it lives in.

Comment: @connexo if the expected result is exactly what's needed, check the answer I provided.

Comment: @connexo are you need a scroll able  .grandparent  x axis or y axis or both ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor Mostly vertical scrolling, but that should not be relevant as you cannot have one dimension scroll and the other visible.

Comment: @connexo may be if you need a scrollable .grandparent .. i think you need to change html mark up ... i post a answer .. plz comment what is wrong with that ?

Answer (score -3):

```css
div, div.child::after {
  border: 3px dashed #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

div::before { content: attr(class); }

.grandparent { overflow: auto; }
.parent { position: relative;}
.child::before{ content: " " }
.child {position: relative; overflow: auto; }
.child::after {content: attr(class); position: absolute; height: 60px; background: black; color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

this is your answer but It does not seem practical
**Because in reality it can not be implemented in this way**

***Please ask your question clearly or with a more practical example***

Comment: I don't see how this achieves anything remotely useful. It does not, in any way, achieve the desired result.