# Set overflow-y visible while overflow-x is auto so that content can vertically overflow parent's container

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

I'm using `position: absolute` and `position: relative` to display text over an image if its parent is hovered over. The container that the text and images parent div is in is set to `overflow-x: auto`, causing it to have a horizontal scrollbar.

**I want the text that appears to vertically overflow the `#container` element** (and the horizontal scrollbar), but this is not happening - instead, a vertical scrollbar is appearing in the container.

I do not want the containers height to expand to the height of the text.

I've tried applying `overflow-y: visible` to `#container` but this hasn't resolved the problem. If I remove `overflow-x: auto` from `#container` it fixes the problem, but removes the horizontal scrollbar from `#container` and puts it on `body` (which I don't want)

```js
function textVisibility(name) {
  var p = document.getElementById(name);
  if (p.style.display == "block") {
    p.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    p.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.div {
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 70%;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="div" onmouseenter="textVisibility(1);" onmouseleave="textVisibility(1)">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p id="1">Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div" onmouseenter="textVisibility(2);" onmouseleave="textVisibility(2)">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p id="2">Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div" onmouseenter="textVisibility(3);" onmouseleave="textVisibility(3)">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p id="3">Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div" onmouseenter="textVisibility(4);" onmouseleave="textVisibility(4)">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p id="4">Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div" onmouseenter="textVisibility(5);" onmouseleave="textVisibility(5)">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p id="5">Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div" onmouseenter="textVisibility(6);" onmouseleave="textVisibility(6)">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p id="6">Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r3Lja69h/

Comment: if you want the text to vertically overlap AND you want an horizontal scrollbar then which one should be on the top? the text or the scrollbar?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The text. I get you might say that this would mean the scrollbar wouldn't be visible, but in my full code each `p` tag only appears when its parent `div` is hovered over (so only one `p` would be visible at a time) - I didn't include this though because I don't feel it's relevant to the question and not needed for the minimum reproducible example

Comment: it's relevant because as you said : *I get you might say that this would mean the scrollbar wouldn't be visible* --> what you want isn't possible if the text is always visible because it doesn't make sense but a hover effect to show one text at a time is a complete dfferent story

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ah I see, anyway yes that is what I'm trying todo

Comment: @TemaniAfif Updated my code to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the use of `position:fixed` and adjust the position dynamically on hover:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.div').forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      var r = div.getBoundingClientRect();
      div.style.setProperty("--t", r.top+"px");
      div.style.setProperty("--l", r.left+"px");
      div.style.setProperty("--w", r.width+"px");
  });
});
```

```css
.div {
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid;
}

img {
  width: 70%;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--t,0);
  left:var(--l,0);
  width:var(--w,0);
  display:none;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.div:hover p {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is brilliant thank you! I've made a slight change and used `var text = div.getElementsByTagName(p)[0];` and then set the style directly like `text.style.top = r.top+"px";` (as opposed to setting the style on the `div`) and it's working fine thank you.

Comment: Could you explain why position fixed is used instead of absolute please

Comment: @TheCodesee fixed consider the viewport as reference so overflow applied on other element (even parent element) will not affect it (hide it) and you can consider the screen as your reference. When using absolute the reference is the first positionned ancestor so overlow on parent element will hide it and even if there is no overflow set the position will be hard to define because your reference can be any element having position:relative.

Answer (score 2):

If either `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` property is neither `visible` nor `clip`, then `visible`/`clip` is calculated as `auto`/`hidden`, respectively.

That is, if you specify `overflow-x: auto;`, `overflow-y` property will also be `auto` (because the default value is `visible`).

> ### 3. Scrolling and Clipping Overflow: the overflow-x, overflow-y, and overflow properties<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties)</sup>
>
> as specified, except with visible/clip computing to auto/hidden (respectively) if one of overflow-x or overflow-y is neither visible nor clip

One solution is to make the absolute placement of the image instead of the text, so that the text determines the height of the container.

```css
.div {
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
    <p>Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text Some very long text
    </p>
  </div>

</div>


<button onclick="toggleText();">Click me
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I don't want the container's height to increase - I want the text to overflow it.

Comment: @TheCodesee It can't. That expected behavior would be against the specification. Change the design.

Comment: Is there a workaround to achieve what I want to accomplish?

Comment: I think I can achieve it using JavaScript by positioning the text, but I'm trying to find out if there is a pure CSS/HTML route.

Comment: @TheCodesee No, that is not possible due to CSS specifications.

Answer (score -2):

If you want X-Axis scrolling and Y-Axis hidden than you write :-

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

If you want Y-Axis scrolling and X-Axis hidden than you write:-

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

If you want all Axis scrollable than you write:-

```
overflow:auto;
```

All Axis hidden than: -

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I want x-axis overflow scrollable, while y-axis overflow visible.

Comment: The spec disallows this combination. If you set `auto` in one dimension and `visible` in the other dimension, the `visible` dimension will behave as `auto`.