# CSS: position:absolute inside position:relative not positioned correctly within overflow-x:visible

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have few dropdown elements in `overflow-x:visible` element, this element is in `position:relative` element so that the element with `position:absolute` can  overflow from the scrollable element. The problem is that the element with `position:absolute` has to be in another `position:relative` element and it doesn't work well when scrolling horizontally.

When scrolling the element dropdown options are not scrolled properly.

Is there a way for dropdown options to scroll as well as the dropdown labels?

[image: Example]

Source:

```js
$('div.dropdown__select').click(function() {
  const optionsElement = $(this).next();

  $('div.dropdown__options').each(function() {
    if (this === optionsElement[0]) {
      return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
  });

  $(this).next().toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
}

div.scrollable {
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

div.dropdown {
  padding: 8px;
}

div.dropdown__select {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}

div.dropdown__options {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown__select">Label</div>
      <div class="dropdown__options hidden">
        <ul>
          <li>Dropdown option #1</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #2</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #3</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #4</li>
          <li>Dropdown option #5</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: almost the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60912860/8620333 you will need more JS to set the position OR the browser will use the default one like you are getting

Comment: Yeah, it's very similiar. I am looking for a solution without JS, if there's any

Comment: you are already using JS ...

Comment: Yeah, but only for showing and hiding dropdown options.

Comment: so you can easily add an extra line to set the correct position and the code will still be *only for showing and hiding dropdown options.*

Comment: I can, just wanted to be sure there's no CSS solution to this.

Comment: Yout html is so bad and don't use Absolute....!
absolute will prevent the scrolling.

Comment: The HTML is just for example, but it's fine. Absolute won't prevent scrolling.